# Why am I getting the following React Native warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to build a React Native app, but am still kind of new to the React/RN ecosystem, so I may just be misunderstanding something obvious with the problem I'm having.

I have an app where a lot of the pages are structured as follows:

```
<View>
    <NavComponent />
    <View>
        {/* Page component structure/logic here */}
    </View>
</View>
```

`NavComponent` loads a toggleable nav menu with `TouchableOpacity` elements like the following:

```
Go to Screen #1
Go to Screen #2
Go to Screen #3
```

The problem I'm having (and maybe this isn't a problem so much as just how React/RN works) is that if I start on screen #1, open the nav, go to screen #2, open the nav again, and then go back to screen #1, even though screen #1 shows up again, the actual rendering function for screen #1 doesn't seem to be called again, and since `NavComponent` is part of the rendering of each screen, when I try to open the nav from screen #1 again, I get the following warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
>   To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a
>   useEffect cleanup function ...

Again, maybe my approach with the app is flawed to begin with, but essentially, when I go from one screen to another from the nav, I always want the new screen to re-render from scratch (including the initial Ajax call for data).

Here's a more fleshed-out example of the render function for a screen (they all follow this same basic pattern):

```
const screen1 = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [serverData, setServerData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // getPageData is a custom method I added to axios.
        axios.getPageData('/api/url/here', (data) => {
            setServerData(data);
        });
    }, []);

    if (serverData) {
        const { meta, user, data } = serverData;

        return (
            <View>
                <NavComponent />
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    {/* Page component structure/logic here */}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    return null;
};
```

If, for example, I added a `console.log` to the beginning of the render function above, it's called the first time the screen is loaded, but if I go to screen #2 and then come back to screen #1 via the nav component, the `console.log` isn't output again. Why?

And for what it's worth, I'm using the standard `navigation.navigate('ScreenName')` in `NavComponent` to go from screen to screen.

Any advice on how to fix the warning (and/or just better design the app) so that I can have that nav on every page would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

your api call is resulting in the warning, in the react/native ecosystem, when a component is removed from the tree, the developer needs to cancel all subscriptions (listeners to events) and async tasks(fetching data from the web), those function need to be canceld by the developer as react/native cant do that for you.

to handle that in a class based component, you need to impelment `componentWillUnmount` and remove the subscriptions there

```
class MyClass extends Component {
   componentWillUnmount() {
     // remove listeners and cancel requests
    }
```

but in a modern hook component , you need to return a **cleanup function**, a function to return in useEffect that will be called by react to cancel any subscriptions you have made, in your case, just return a cleanup function should remove that warning for you

```
  const [mounted, setIsMounted] useState(false)
 useEffect(() => {
        // getPageData is a custom method I added to axios.
        setIsMounted(true)
        axios.getPageData('/api/url/here', (data) => {
            if(isMounted)
             setServerData(data);
        });

        return () => {
             setIsMounted(false)
         }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Ahmed, thanks for explaining that. I was completely unaware of that. Unfortunately, I added that empty callback function return to `useEffect`, but I still get the same error as before, and I'm still not seeing the `console.log` that I added to the top of screen #1 to ensure that it's re-rendering each time. Also, even though I didn't originally have it, I added a `useEffect` hook to `NavComponent` and returned an empty function, but I'm still getting the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: what about screen#2 @HartleySan

Comment: Yes, I did it on both. No change.

Comment: this article might help you https://juliangaramendy.dev/use-promise-subscription/

Comment: Ahmed, this is interesting, but after further investigation, I am seeing a few things: 1) The warning only occurs on screen #1, which is the screen that is loaded automatically after logging into the app. 2) If I change the screen that is loaded after you log in from screen #1 to screen #2, then the warning occurs for only screen #2. 3) The warning seems to be related to the fact that all other screens are properly reloading every time I navigate to them, except for the initial screen loaded from logging in. I don't even need to return `() => {};` to force that to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe in your login screen you are doingn something that causes this

Comment: More specifically, `useEffect` is only called the first time the initial page is loaded, but it's called every time for all other pages. For the login screen, I post the user's login creds to the server, and upon receiving a positive response, I am doing the following: `navigation.navigate('Screen1');`. Why would that be weird?

Comment: dose the warning say which screen caused that, usullay the do !!

Comment: That's a good question, Ahmed. What's interesting is that even though the issue(s) seem to be on screen #1, the error points to `NavComponent` being the issue on screen #2. The error points very specifically to the `<NavComponent />` line on screen #2. So confused. Also, thank you so much for your help.